# PlatformNotSupportedException for HttpClient and Await/Async operation at PCL and Xamarin.iOS app

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, async-await, portable-class-library

I'm trying to add await/async support to my Portable Class Library.
In my Xamarin.iOS project I created a reference to PCL (profile 78).
Every time I'm trying to call PCL async method:

```
var result = await new Class1().Do();
```

I'm getting the following error (stacktrace):

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: This platform is not supported.

2014-03-29 17:48:06.634 HelloWorld5[2014:60b] Unhandled managed exception: This platform is not supported. (System.PlatformNotSupportedException)
  at System.ExecutionContextLightup.Run (System.ExecutionContextLightup executionContext, System.Action`1 callback, System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter+<>c__DisplayClassa.<OnCompletedInternal>b__1 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIKitSynchronizationContext+<Post>c__AnonStorey89.<>m__A9 () [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/.pmcs-compat.UIKitSynchronizationContext.cs:24 
  at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSAsyncActionDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/maccore/src/Foundation/.pmcs-compat.NSAction.cs:87 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string
[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/.pmcs-compat.UIApplication.cs:38 
  at HelloWorld5.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in c:\Downloads\HelloWorld5.BackgroundTest\HelloWorld5\HelloWorld5\Main.cs:17 
The program 'Mono' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Debugging session ended.
The program '[5932] HelloWorld5.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[5932] HelloWorld5.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I'm using STABLE version of Xamarin software.
Please find the sample project here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19503836/PCLAndAsyncWithXamariniOS.zip

Comment: Is this fixed since the code drop isn't available anymore? You might have needed a binding redirect in the app.config.

Comment: I guess yes, as since then a lot of updates was done to Xamarin.iOS